# consumable item design in RPG game java

Tags: java, oop

right now I'm trying to write a simple Java program about Japanese RPG game mechanic.
I have trouble on implementing use of consumable items, that is, Items that change a specific status, either from variable HP or MP in 'character' class. Here is a rough code for class 'Item' right now:

```
abstract class Items{
int stock;

public int checkCategory();
public int use();
}

class HPitems extends Items{

public int checkCategory(){
return 1; // this only means that category '1' heals HP, not MP
}

}

class Potion extends HPitems{

public int use(){
stock--;
return 50; //this means potion heals 50 HP
}

}
```

so I believe you get the idea by now, I was planning to make class MPitems extends Items that return category 2. and Whenever my player object consume an item, using consume(Items e), it will check the category using multiple if statements. If Category 1 is returned, I will use the value returned from use() of the corresponding Items subclass, and add the value to player HP.I don't think there's any problem now, but if there are many Items category, such as Items that gives another status effects, I figured it won't be efficient. Is there's any better way to do this?

and by the way, this is the player class if you need it:

```
public class Player{
int HP;
int MP;

public void consume(Items e){
if(e.checkCategory() == 1){
    this.HP = this.HP+e.use();
else{
    this.MP = this.MP+e.use();
}
}

} // consume

}
```

Comment: You could give the use method the player as an Argument: use(Player p) and then in the Potion class use(Player p) { p.HP += 50 } this way you will not need many if-clauses. On the other side the use-function now is bound to a player. If other objects need to "use" a potion as well, I would create a new class Character eg and define use(Character c). Player would then inherit from character. The consume method would then just look like this consume(Items e) { e.use(this) } independent of the Items-Type. Btw convention it should be Item and not Items :)

Comment: @Michael nice. very nice :D thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `e.checkCategory`, use more natural approach by dispatching

```
class Player {
    int hp; 
    int mp;

    void use(Potion p) {
        p.use(this);
    }
}

interface Potion {
    void use(Player p);
}

class HPPotion implements Potion {
    public void use(Player p) {
        p.hp += 50;
    }
}

class MPPotion implements Potion {
    public void use(Player p) {
        p.mp += 50;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying. that's what I'm looking for, thank you :D

Comment: That dude stole my answer :P

Comment: @Michael, sorry for that)